# Hide a Subview when the parentView is flipped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, rotation, subview

Here is what I am try to do :

Imagine my parentView as a book cover. This view has an UIImageView subView.
My problem is that when I flip the parentView for 180° (I open the book), I can still see the UIImageSubview in front of it. I would like the inside of my cover to be just white.

The only idea I came with was hide the UIImageView subview at half of the rotation but I don't think it is really smart.

If you guys can help me,

Thank's

EDIT : I'm actually using

```
        [UIView animateWithDuration:someDuration animations:^{
             viewToTransform.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform,
                         (M_PI * 0.999 * -dir), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
       }];
```

I'm gonna try to hide when the rotation > PI/2

I'll keep you updated,

```
        [UIView animateWithDuration:someDuration animations:^{
             viewToTransform.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform,
                         (M_PI * 0.999 * -dir), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
             _coverImage.hidden = atan2f(viewToTransform.layer.transform.m12, viewToTransform.layer.transform.m11) > M_PI_2 ? YES : NO;
       }];
```

This doesn't work, cause it hides the subview at the begining of the animation :'(

Comment: Why isn't it smart? You want to hide the subview halfway through the transformation, so hiding the subview is what you ought to do.

Comment: What method do you use to flip parentView ? Are you using UIView animations ? It should be fairly easy to hide views if you use UIView animations api.

Comment: If you are already animating with UIView animations, you could try animating the UIImageView's alpha to 0 to make it slowly disappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide the image view, try the following code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:someDuration animations:^{
         viewToTransform.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform,
                     (M_PI * 0.999 * -dir), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
   }];

[_coverImage performSelector:@selector(setHidden:) withObject:@YES afterDelay:(someDuration/2)];
```

A better solution would be to set the alpha of image view, in a new `UIView animateWithDuration..` block just after the flip animation, with half the duration:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:someDuration animations:^{

         viewToTransform.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform,
                     (M_PI * 0.999 * -dir), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
   }];

[UIView animateWithDuration:someDuration/2 animations:^{

         _coverImage.alpha = 0.0f;
   }];
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, i prefer the first solution which is way more realistic, i just had to do small small adjustements, but thank you for the perform selector idea

Answer (score 0):

The following code will allow you to hide your sub view section once the animation is finished.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0
  animations:^{
    //Animation code goes here
  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    //Code to run once the animation is completed goes here
}];
```

As you can see, the UI view element has a completion event that fires after the animation, meaning it's quite easy to hook it to do what you need.

Comment: Thanks but i can't wait till the animation is finished, i need to do it at half of it :)